# Video uploads to YouTube with no sound

Tags: video, youtube, video-encoding

I have a video camera which, when I try to upload the videos to Youtube taken with it, the sound is removed. I used to be able o upload sound but then something happened and ...now I can't. If something did, indeed, happen I'm not sure what it was.

Codec info (as discovered through VLC) for videos that did work on my computer and when uploaded to Youtube:

Before upload to Youtube, when sound plays on my computer

```
video codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part10)(H264)
audio codec: MPEG AAC (mp4a)
```

After upload to youtube [where sound played] then download from Youtube [and played on my computer where the sound played]

```
video codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part10)(avc1)
audio codec: MPEG AAC (mp4a)
```

Codec info (as discovered through VLC) for video that did work on my computer but did NOT work when uploaded to Youtube:

Before upload to Youtube, when sound plays on my computer

```
video codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part10)(H264) 
audio codec: MPEG AAC (mp4a)
```

After upload to youtube [where no sound played] then download from Youtube [and played on my computer where the sound played]

```
video codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part10)(avc1)
audio codec: MPEG AAC (mp4a)
```

You can see the codecs for working and non-working files seems to be the same. There are no setting on the camera for changing the audio/video encodings (the camera is a Toshiba Camileo S20, a pretty base model pocket camcorder, FWIW). I have uploaded videos using the software which comes with the camera (which allows a one click upload to my Youtube account) as well as by uploading through the traditional Youtube web interface.

Any thoughts on why the sound is now being cut off?

**Edit**

Some other things I tried previously which still didn't allow me to hear sound when uploaded to Youtube

- Changed the container from avi to wav
- changed audio codec to mp3

Comment: So your saying you cannot here the sound on your videos but you can here it when you download your video from YouTube?

Comment: The is sound before I upload but not after. There *used* to be sounds on Youtube, but no longer. No Youtube sound.

Comment: Just your videos or all YouTube videos?

Comment: Just mine. Everyone else's behave normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, YouTube just doesn't like a certain file format. The camera may be creating the file in such a way that YouTube just can't decode the audio layer. Try using a program like [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to re-encode the video before uploading it. This would ensure that it is encoded in a way that YouTube will definitely be able to understand, as long as HandBrake itself is capable of handling the audio. HandBrake is free software, and it has very good speed and quality, but if you are worried about quality, you can change the settings.

Comment: What setting does YouTube prefer? I've tried changing the container type, and the audio codec to several different things. I've been doing this through VLC though. I can try HandBrake tonight.

Comment: @Brad You should be fine using the default settings of HandBrake. Just drag your video file onto HandBrake's window, set the destination folder by clicking Browse, and then click Start.

Comment: *> Sometimes, YouTube just doesn't like a certain combination of codecs.*   He has clearly demonstrated two files which were encoding using identical codecs, but one worked and one did not.

Comment: @Synetech I have clarified my answer. I didn't necessarily mean only the codecs. It could be anything else about the file, but HandBrake would surely output a clean file.

Comment: I'm confused about what HandBrake did. But whatever it did do seemed to work. I resaved the file using the default settings and now there is sound on YouTube. When I download the file from Youtube though and look at the codecs they are just the same as when they didn't work. I'll try this with some more previously-non-working videos this weekend and if they continue to have sound I thin we have a bounty winner :)

Comment: @Brad I'm glad to hear that it worked. What HandBrake did was basically read your file as it was, and re-encode it into a safe, clean format. For whatever reason, YouTube just has a problem with the files that your camera creates.

Comment: I have not had anytime to try this on the other files but it worked on the one so as of now you get the bounty!